# select portlet id through javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, selector, portlet

I have a form inside a java-ee portlet, how can I select this element using jQuery or JavaScript?

```
<form id="pb_ForecastPortlet_WAR_FileSearchPortlet_INSTANCE_UDcNUDEje4L2_j_id1:summary-form" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form element has id assigned to it, you can use id selector(you need to escape CSS notation characters used in ID) or attribute equal selector:

```
var formobj = $('#pb_ForecastPortlet_WAR_FileSearchPortlet_INSTANCE_UDcNUDEje4L2_j_id1\\:summary-form')
```

or

```
var formobj = $('[id="pb_ForecastPortlet_WAR_FileSearchPortlet_INSTANCE_UDcNUDEje4L2_j_id1:summary-form"]')
```

Comment: the main problem with that is, that the instance id may change, i've found another solution for me working here, but thank you for your fast response. I'm using var $('[id$="summary-form"]'); now